# Bridge from loop tools not connecting right

Tags: vertices

I've been trying to connect the head of my model to the neck though its not connecting to the right vertices.
[image: I want them to connect as multiple rectangle but it keeps coming up as this.]

[image]

Comment: Please provide blend file

Comment: Try to adjust the Twist on the left-bottom.

Comment: If you disable the mirror, you can see the neck is on the opposite side of the head: https://i.imgur.com/nZ5dirF.png

Comment: The answer was I applied the mirror modifier on the wrong side and deleted the wrong side. then tried to join. Thank you Markus for the answer.